# Using GROUP BY and ORDER BY in my query works in MySQL but not in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which runs correctly on MySQL server. In SQL Server it gives error:

> "Column 'Tovar.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" .

I don't know how to convert it in to SQL Server. Looking forward 
for the help from guru's.

```sql
SELECT B.BBarcode,
       Name, C.Country,
       Manufacturer,W.id,
       Packtype,
       B.TovarId,
       SUM(WCount) as count,
       Price,
       Series,
       ExpDate
FROM Warehouse W, Tovar T, Barcodes B, Countries C 
WHERE C.CId=T.Country
   AND B.WarehouseId=W.id
   AND WCount>0
   AND T.id=W.TovarId +'=@param' 
GROUP BY W.ID,B.BBarcode 
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: All those non-aggregated columns must be in `GROUP BY` clause.  Your query will only run in MySQL.  Your query won't even run in any other dbms because it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also use a proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? those are two very different database products.

Answer (score 1):

To make this run all of the columns in the select have to be in the group by portion of the query.

```
Select B.BBarcode , Name, C.Country, Manufacturer,W.id,
 Packtype, B.TovarId, sum(WCount) as count, Price, Series, ExpDate
  from Warehouse W, Tovar T, Barcodes B, 
  Countries C 
  where C.CId=T.Country and
   B.WarehouseId=W.id and WCount>0 and 
   T.id=W.TovarId +'=@param' 
   GROUP BY B.BBarcode , Name, C.Country, Manufacturer,W.id,
 Packtype, B.TovarId, Price, Series, ExpDate
   ORDER BY Name
```

However I’m not sure the query will run with the where syntax you have, specifically the `T.id=W.TovarId +'=@param'` portion.

That can be refactored to be either

`T.id=W.TovarId and T.id = @param`

Or

```
T.id=W.TovarId and W.TovarId= @param
```

Version that should execute

```
Select B.BBarcode , Name, C.Country, Manufacturer,W.id,
 Packtype, B.TovarId, sum(WCount) as count, Price, Series, ExpDate
  from Warehouse W, Tovar T, Barcodes B, 
  Countries C 
  where C.CId=T.Country and
   B.WarehouseId=W.id and WCount>0 and 
   T.id=W.TovarId and T.Id = @param
   GROUP BY B.BBarcode , Name, C.Country, Manufacturer,W.id,
 Packtype, B.TovarId, Price, Series, ExpDate
   ORDER BY Name
```

I would also look at some documents on how [sql server does joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017) and the [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). While I believe sql server will do the joins correctly for an inner join between the tables based on how you’ve written them, the syntax structure they have make it a little more clear what is joining to what as well as the options to do other types of joins

Comment: Thanks aaron , your query worked . But instead of adding all the fields in the Group by clause Iam trying with Join by clause .

Answer (score 1):

MySQL lets you "get away" with "sloppy" queries like this.

Other DBMSs do not. 
SQL Server is one of them.

When using an aggregating query, you **must** do one or the other with *every* field in the select list - "group by" it, or aggregate it.

Here's why:

```
select * from table1 ; 

+---+----+---+ 
| A | B  | C | 
+---+----+---+ 
| 1 | 10 | Z | 
| 1 | 20 | Y | 
| 1 | 30 | X | 
| 2 | 40 | W | 
+---+----+---+ 

select A, sum( B ) SB, C 
from table1
group by A 
order by A ; 

+---+----+---+ 
| A | SB | C | 
+---+----+---+ 
| 1 | 60 | ? | <-- What values goes here? 'X', 'Y' or 'Z'? 
| 2 | 40 | W | 
+---+----+---+
```

Unless you *tell* the DBMS how to deal with these "stray" values, it *cannot* reliably determine the result should be, so it *gives up* and throws the error.

The reason that you "get away" with it in MySQL is that *it* takes the attitude of ...

> If you don't care which value you want, nor do I!

... and gives you *any one* of the values, with no rhyme or reason as to which.

Comment: I think MySQL's attitude is better described as "Prevent error message at all costs, even if that means returning random results or ignoring data consistency"